# Bootstrap file-input

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Has someone used this library? I have a question that I am working on for hours, and I can't find a way to fix it. Is it possible to remove the Upload button from the footer, and if yes how?

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUbTy.png)

[Link to the library](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way to fix this! If someone has problems with it in future the way to fix it is:

```
<script>
$("#yourClass").fileinput({
        layoutTemplates: {
        actionUpload: ""
    }
});
</script>
```